# ClassCastException when sending 2D array through intent using a bundle

Tags: android, arrays, classcastexception

I'm trying to send a 2D array through an Intent by using Bundle.putSerializable, but am getting a ClassCastException error when retrieving it.

The code I'm using is more or less exactly what other StackOverflow users have reported as working for them, so I'm not certain why I'm getting this error.

I have a 2D Array which I add to my Bundle and Intent as follows:

```
String[][] myString= new String[myGroup.length][myGroup[0].length];
//Data is added to String here
Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
myBundle.putSerializable("myString", myString);
intent.putExtras(myBundle);
```

And retrieve in the next Activity as follows:

```
Bundle myBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String[][] myNewString= (String[][]) myBundle.getSerializable("myString");
```

However, at Runtime I get the error:

**java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[[][]**

And I'm not certain why, as other users seemingly reported success with this. Would I be better served taking another approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What API level is the error generally appear on?

Comment: It's being run on rooted 4.4, so level 19 I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hope this help....**

Retrieve data in the next Activity as

```
String[][] myNewString=null;
Object[] objectArray = (Object[]) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("myString");
if(objectArray!=null){
    myNewString = new String[objectArray.length][];
    for(int i=0;i<objectArray.length;i++){
        myNewString[i]=(String[]) objectArray[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the solution I was getting ready to implement; however, I'm curious why casting straight to a String[][] was reported to work for some people whereas it clearly wasn't for me. Any idea?

Comment: This works and I'm marking it as the correct answer. Still curious why it's necessary though.